# How to convert hexadecimal in python?

Tags: python

I have file which contains in each line some hexadecimal numbers. For example:

```
5B35E8DF4A709CA16A1C8BC29022E83C
28958FA134D53BE6F382D04DC9891922
C67FC50F905F043EBEFEBFAF243B8744
99DCD61A89EE5553DDCA44378C3CE3C6
...........
```

I want to  convert them from uppercase to lowercase. For example:

```
5b35e8df4a709ca16a1c8bc29022e83c

Srcpath  ='Uppercase_File'
Destpath ='Lowercase_File'
with open(Srcpath, 'r') as f:
    with open(Destpath, 'w') as fp:
        for key in f:
            print(key)
            #key_Separated=[key[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(key), 2)]
            rejoined = key.replace(" ","").decode('hex')
            print(rejoined)
            fp.write(rejoined)
    fp.close()
```

My code gives me this error:

```
rejoined = key.decode('hex')
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

Comment: What's wrong with [`s.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to convert a value from decimal to hex:

```
>>> hex(65)
'0x41'
```

But if you only want to convert the letters to lowercase, why don't you use .lower() method:

```
>>> s = "AABA67A79A"
>>> s.lower()
'aaba67a79a'
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html